# How to maintain cloned content in jQuery on a asp.net control click?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

```js
 $("#Add").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var group = $('#oldDiv').clone().attr("id", "newDiv" + i);
        $(group).appendTo("#container");
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
<div id="oldDiv">
<Button runat="server" id="Add">Add+</Button><br><br>
</div>
</div>


<asp:Button ID="BtnShow" runat="server" Text="Show" />
```

I have a button and by this button I am adding some content in a div using jQuery. I also have a asp.net control and when I click it then my added content get removed due to Postback. What should I do in order to prevent asp.net control from performing postback and maintain my added contents.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

**asp.net**:

```
<Button runat="server" id="Add" onclick="return myFunction()">Add+</Button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function myFunction() {
        var group = $('#oldDiv').clone().attr("id", "newDiv" + i);
        $(group).appendTo("#container");
        return false;
 };
```

**snippet**:

```js
    function myFunction() {
            var group = $('#oldDiv').clone().attr("id", "newDiv" + 1);
            $(group).appendTo("#container");
            return false;
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
<div id="oldDiv">
<Button  runat="server" id="Add" onclick="return myFunction()">Add+</Button>
</div>
</div>


<asp:Button ID="BtnShow" runat="server" Text="Show" />
```